# Lazy sequence doesn't work in stack-consuming recursive calls

Tags: recursion, clojure, lazy-evaluation

I found a simple(but inefficient) solution to a problem which basically can be written like this in Clojure:

```
(defn make-someof [data]
  (fn sumf
    ([x n ds]
     (if (= n 1)
       (if (some #{x} ds) 1 0)
       (reduce + (for [m (filter #(< % n) ds)]
                   (sumf (- x m) (dec n) (disj ds m))))))
    ([x n] (sumf x n data))))
```

Which could be called like this:

```
((make-someof #{1 2 3 4 5 6}) 7 2)
```

But as it turns out, the form in the reduce section of the `make-sumof` function gets evaluated only once. (i.e. the `filter` form which has 6 values in it get iterated only for it's first value!)

I also tried using `doall` on the `for` form, thus forcing it to get computed, but the moment recursive call reaches the first form (when condition `(= n 1)` is held) the resulting expression (in this case 1 in the `(if (some #{x} ds) 1 0)` form) is returned as the result of the whole invocation chain.

It just doesn't make sense to me.
Maybe I'm making a big mistake or it's a bug in Clojure?

Note: This function is supposed to count the number of ways which the number 7 could be written as the sum of 2 other numbers from specific distinct numbers (in this case `#{1 2 3 4 5 6}`).
I'm rather interested in figuring out what's happening here, as this function could be written with a `loop` form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter predicate `#(< % n)` is meant to remove numbers from the set of available addends that are larger than the remaining target sum, but instead it's testing for addends that are less than the number of addends `n`. Try using `#(< % x)` instead.

Comment: BTW, your function counts 3 + 4 and 4 + 3 as two ways. Is that what you want? This would be easier to solve using math.combinatorics.

Comment: As an aside, you can also express your `for` statement using the `:where` condition, as `(for [m ds :where (< m x)] ...)`.  I think this is easier to read, and it might make this kind of error easier to spot.  See [here](http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.7.0/clj/clojure.core/for/) for more info.

Comment: @Diego, Actually when 3 + 4 is counted, 4 + 3 returns 0 (thus doesn't count).

Comment: @Diego, Yep, You're right. I didn't notice I fixed that in the second version I wrote!